# how to trigger firebase cloud function on read event

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

It is possible to trigger cloud functions [on write events](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events), but I can't find any documentation for triggering after reading (eg, `firebase.database().ref().once('value')...`).

Any recommendations on the best way to go about handling this use case?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no trigger for responding to client reads.  It's assumed that apps will have massive amounts of reads, and having code run for each of those reads would be incredibly expensive.  If you want to run some code when the client performs some action, have the client call an HTTPS function when that action should occur.

Comment: Yeah, that was what I was afraid of. 

In this case, there is a particular resource that doesn't get read as often, but when it does, we want to make a call to an external API refresh the resource's data. 

This might be better reserved for a separate question, but happen to have any guesses whether there would be any noticeable performance difference using an HTTP function?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.  I've only proposed one feasible option, so I can't tell you what's the difference between that and some other unknown option.  I will say that any time a network connection is involved, performance can vary wildly based on the quality of the connection.

Comment: Often it can be useful to know how many times a document has been read (like Stackoverflow for example...), but to update a counter for each read doubles the bill in the best case scenario. It would be nice to have this feature in the metadata of each document, especially considering that somewhere the reads are already counted for billing purposes.